# Show/Hide specific rows in table when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

I have a table which contains **categories of info on each row** and many rows may have the same category.

I have a menu of all the categories (a very simple vertical text menu in a div).

```html
<div class="menu">
    <a href="">Category 1</a>
    <a href="">Category 2</a>
    <a href="">Category 3</a>
</div>

<table border="1">
    <tr id="cat1">
        <td>some info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="cat2">
        <td>blah blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="cat1">
        <td>more blah</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I **click on a specific category** link in that menu I want it to **only show the rows that match that category** in the table.

---

I'm new to Javascript, etc so still learning. I've searched on Google but can only find examples that seem to hide/show 1 row or something similar but not what I need it to do. I can't work out if it's possible to do what I described above. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Show us what You have tried.

Comment: You want to give your rows a class or an attribute by which they can be selected. Ideally it matches the value of your category list.

Comment: Its just a very simple vertical text menu in a div on the left like the example below:
```
    <div class="menu">
<a href="">Category 1</a>
<BR>
<a href="">Category 2</a>
<br>
<a href="">Category 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using anchors if you do not want their behaviour?

Comment: We are asking for a well written questions. that explains well you need, give enough and minimum code to reproduce your cas and work on it. and most importantly shows what tried and the single issue that you are struggling with.

Comment: "Why are you using anchors if you do not want their behaviour? – 
Lain" - I don't know what you mean??

Comment: I've not tried anything to make it work as I can't figure out how to do it which is the issue I am struggling with.

Comment: [Element.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

Comment: anchors are meant to navigate between pages, use buttons to fire actions instead, or any element that has not a default behavior

Comment: I thought you could use an on-click event on the menu items to trigger the script to do what I need it to do. Is this not the case?

Comment: you can but anchor are meant to navigate there is no reason to use them to do something else, just use a paragraph with an onclick event or something else if you don't want to use buttons

Comment: Do you have any feedback on my answer ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I can see it works great when I click on "run code snippet". I have just copied the code onto a test html page on my laptop but it doesn't work for some reason, nothing happens when I click the buttons. I put the top section of your code inside <script> tags, the middle into <style> tags and the bottom code into the main body. Have I done something wrong there?

Comment: Did you put the script at the end of `<body></body>` ? please continue your futur comments under my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues in your code

1. You need to identify your table rows by category.

   - Using `id` to assign a category to multiple rows is wrong (Duplicate ID values is invalid HTML).
   - You can use `class`, but personally I prefer to `attributes` since that value is meant to use within **JS** and not styling.
2. The default behavior of `anchors` is to redirect, refresh (or move the scrollbar), to make it short this isn't the element you need to use. I will replace it with a `button`.

## A solution

```js
// Selecting all the filters (buttons)
document.querySelectorAll('[catFilter]').forEach((el)=>{
  //console.log(el);
  
  // Listenning to clicks on the filters
  el.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
  
    // Selecting all the table rows when the click happens
    // This will happen everytime you click!
    document.querySelectorAll('table tr').forEach((row)=>{
      //console.log(row);
      
      if(ev.target.value === "*"){
        // Show all
        row.classList.remove('hidden');
      }else if(row.hasAttribute(ev.target.value)){
        // Make sure that the filtered rows are shown
        row.classList.remove('hidden');
      }else{
        // Hide everything else
        row.classList.add('hidden');
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button value="cat1" catFilter>cat1</button>
<button value="cat2" catFilter>cat2</button>
<button value="*" catFilter>All categories</button>

<table border="1">
    <tr cat1>
        <td>some info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr cat2>
        <td>blah blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr cat1>
        <td>more blah</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I put the script between the <head></head> tags

Comment: @KevinBeswick The script code needs to be loaded **after the rendering of your HTML body** otherwise the **querySelector** will select nothing because it will try to do that before the elements even exist. Conventionally we add scripts at the end of body `<body>...<script>...</script></body>`. **Putting scrpits in head slows the page loading**

Comment: Ah, I see. I was always shown to add script in the head section. I've amended it as you said and it now works great. A thousand thank yous for your help. I'll now work on adding this to my main table that I want it to work on.

Comment: You are welcome :) avoid any documentation that showed the use of script in head, I assume that it is an obsolete documentation.

Comment: Sorry, just one more question - What would I need to change in the code if I was to add a button "All" that when clicked shows all of the categories?

Comment: @KevinBeswick solved with the latest edit