# How to hide a table row or result if checkbox is checked AND if 0 result/count

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this counter for word occurrence in the textarea. The problem is, I have a lot of items in the table, and so it can be distracting to include the zero results.

So what I'm hoping to achieve is, if the user checks the checkbox, it will not show the zero results anymore (preferably the whole row)..

Please see the code so far:

```js
let textarea = $('#textarea3');
textarea.on('keyup', _ => counting());
function counting() {
    var searchText = $('#textarea3').val();

    let words = [];
    words['1 sample'] = '#one';
    words['2 sample'] = '#two';
    words['3 sample'] = '#three';
    words['4 sample'] = '#four';
    words['5 sample'] = '#five';
    words['6 sample'] = '#six';

    for (const word in words) {
        var outputDiv = $(words[word]);
        outputDiv.empty();
        let count = searchText.split(word).length - 1;
        searchText = searchText.replaceAll(word,'');
        outputDiv.append('<a>' + count + '</a>');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="checkbox">
<label> Don't show zero results</label><br>
<button onclick="counting();">Count</button>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Items</th>
            <th scope="col">Count</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1 sample</td>
            <td><a id="one"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2 sample</td>
            <td><a id="two"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3 sample</td>
            <td><a id="three"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4 sample</td>
            <td><a id="four"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5 sample</td>
            <td><a id="five"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6 sample</td>
           <td><a id="six"></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<textarea id="textarea3" rows="5">
1 sample
2 sample
3 sample
5 sample
</textarea>
```

If the checkbox isn't checked, it should function as is and still show all results.

I've seen this post but I'm not really sure how to implement it to my own project. [Show or hide table row if checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621174/show-or-hide-table-row-if-checkbox-is-checked)

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71437725/show-hide-specific-rows-in-table-when-link-is-clicked/71438067#71438067 helpful ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Why are you using the `<a>` tag in this context? Is it going to be a link in the future? And you're using the `words` array as an object, which probably should just be an object.

Comment: What are you actually trying to build? The above seems like you're going in the wrong direction with that task... Also `words['1 sample'] = '#one';` is just not the way to use arrays.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Hi, I just found the usage of it from a post in SO, but it would be nice if you can show me the proper way to do it. The objective of the tool is to count the occurrences of each specified word. Now, I'd like to add the ability to hide zero results.

Comment: It's like instead of manually hitting Ctrl + F to find each word, I use this tool to count it all for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var textarea = $('#textarea3');
  var words = [];
  $("table tbody tr").each(function(i, row) {
    words.push({
      term: $("td:eq(0)", row).text().trim(),
      rel: "#" + $("a", row).attr("id"),
      count: 0
    });
  });

  function count() {
    var searchText = textarea.val();
    $.each(words, function(i, word) {
      if (searchText.indexOf(word.term) >= 0) {
        var re = new RegExp('(' + word.term + ')', 'gi');
        word.count = searchText.match(re).length;
        $(word.rel).html(word.count);
      } else {
        word.count = 0;
        if (!$("#noShowZero").is(":checked")) {
          $(word.rel).html(word.count);
        } else {
          $(word.rel).html("");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  textarea.keyup(count);

  $("#count-btn, #noShowZero").click(count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="noShowZero" type="checkbox">
<label> Don't show zero results</label><br>
<button id="count-btn">Count</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Items</th>
      <th scope="col">Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1 sample</td>
      <td>
        <a id="one"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2 sample</td>
      <td>
        <a id="two"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3 sample</td>
      <td>
        <a id="three"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4 sample</td>
      <td>
        <a id="four"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5 sample</td>
      <td>
        <a id="five"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6 sample</td>
      <td>
        <a id="six"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<textarea id="textarea3" rows="5">
1 sample
2 sample
3 sample
5 sample
</textarea>
```

When the User:

- Enters text in the textbox
- Clicks the checkbox
- Clicks the Button

then `count` function is executed.

Count will review all the words and look for specific keywords. A count of them is also retained, as well as element relationship to show that count.

Using Regular Expressions, we can search for the words in the text and count them using `.match()`. It returns an Array of the matches. You could also use `.replace()`, to remove them.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to respond. This should be great help for me. Thank you ^_^